# Importing and Installing Siema

Tags: javascript, html, css, siema

I was looking to import a javascript carousel framework called Siema (https://pawelgrzybek.github.io/siema/) into some HTML to test for some other projects.

I'm semi-new to coding and was wondering how I would actually import the framework into my code which is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

</head>

<body>

<div class="siema">
  <div><img src="pic.png" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="pic.png" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="pic.png" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="pic.png" alt=""></div>
</div>

<script src="siema.min.js"></script>
<script>
  new Siema();
</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Here's the file that this runs from:

[image: ROOT]

I downloaded the latest .zip file from github but I'm not sure what inside of it needs to go where...

At the moment, my page just displays the four images stacked on top of each other.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I just ran a complete search of my PC for files by a certain name and eventually found the right file after a few hours of trial and error. For anyone else with a similar issue, run a search of your pc for a file called siema.min.js

:)